# Why this code executes 89% faster than the other to find HTML elements? What is the difference?

Tags: c#, performance, xpath, html-agility-pack

Imagine the following code:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax = false;
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
htmlDoc.OptionOutputOptimizeAttributeValues = false;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html); /*Where html is a string of 5MB size.*/

/*First approach to select all "anchor" elements*/
HtmlNodeCollection coll = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*/a");
if (coll != null && coll.Count > 0)
    ReplaceSourceLinks(coll, "href");
```

The above code is supposed to load a ~5MB HTML string and replace all those 9567 anchors' href found in the HTML with something suitable for the App. The above code takes 1998ms to execute.

So I decided to replace those 3 last lines displayed above with the following code, i.e., instead of using XPATH to address those anchors, I decided to use the following code:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> coll = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
if (coll != null)
    ReplaceSourceLinks(coll, "href");
```

The new approach takes only 220ms to execute! Almost 89% faster from the first approach. I just want to know whether those codes are identical. Do they address the same set of anchors? (well the second one also selects the same 9567 elements, by the way). Why the heck the second approach executes 89% faster?

Thank you.

Comment: did you clear cache between two tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into its [source code](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs) you'll find that the `SelectNodes` method has to do a much havier work like evaluating the `XPath` and finding the nodes:

```
public HtmlNodeCollection SelectNodes(string xpath)
{
    HtmlNodeCollection list = new HtmlNodeCollection(null);

    HtmlNodeNavigator nav = new HtmlNodeNavigator(_ownerdocument, this);
    XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select(xpath);
    while (it.MoveNext())
    {
        HtmlNodeNavigator n = (HtmlNodeNavigator) it.Current;
        list.Add(n.CurrentNode);
    }
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

whereas the `Descendants` method just loops over the cached `ChildNodes` and checks the element's name:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all descendant nodes with matching name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Descendants(string name)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode node in Descendants())
        if (node.Name == name)
            yield return node;
}
```

Other helper methods used in the above call:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all Descendant nodes for this node and each of child nodes
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> DescendantNodes()
{
    foreach (HtmlNode node in ChildNodes)
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (HtmlNode descendant in node.DescendantNodes())
            yield return descendant;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Gets all Descendant nodes in enumerated list
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Descendants()
{
    foreach (HtmlNode node in DescendantNodes())
    {
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One difference is the cost of parsing the XPath expression, but I wouldn't expect that to cause such a difference. From the source code given by @t3chb0t, it seems that the main difference is caused by the fact that the XPath solution builds a list in memory, whereas the direct method returns an iterator. You don't say how many elements are selected, but building a list is going to cost: it seems to be a fairly inevitable consequence of a poorly-designed API.